# got EndpointNotFoundException when consuming WCFService in A webrole from B webrole

Tags: wcf, azure, webrole

I have a webrole for hosting a web application, and another webrole for hosting a WCF service. Now I have got my WCF service webrole published on windows Azure, but the webrole with web application is not since I am still developing it. Then when I try to consuming the WCF service which has published on cloud in the web application, it gives the error:EndpointNotFoundException, the inner exception is remote server is not found. 
But actually, I can comsuming the WCF service in a web application which is not a Azure project. so is it because web application in one webrole can't consume WCF service in another webrole?

Answer (score 0):

It should be able to as long as they both aren't in Azure.  At that point you will need an InternalEndpoint instead for them to communicate through.  Did you add it as a web reference in Visual Studio and that worked correctly?  Can you browse to the WCF service from the browser and see it?  My guess would be that it has the wrong port, maybe you just manually updated the reference after publishing it to Azure.